# django database reconnect with different user

Tags: django, database-connection, user-management

The background of this is, that I want to have restricted user management, without having the frontend application having full access to the database (creation of the user-tables is done by a backend-process and). The frontend should -only- be allowed to access the tables that the current logged-in user has rights to read to. The reason for that is, that a security problem in the frontend should not reveal access to the whole database but only in worst case to the current user's stuff while I can read from the database randomly without bothering the backend-process.

Therefore I would like to have the Django model connecting with an given user instead of the one in settings.py that has global access to the django database.

Is this somehow possible without overwriting the core db-connection?

Answer (score 0):

From Django 1.2 or later, you can define multiple databases in your settings.py. Whilst I have never used this to point to the same database, I can't see any reason you wouldn't be able to define multiple connections to the same database but with different user credentials.

You could then decide which connection to use based on the logged in user (or non logged in user as the case may be) in your database router(s)

The docs for this are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).

I found their choice to use an app called 'auth' as an example confusing, but it is just an app like any other, so don't get confused in to thinking it is anything to do with auth, even though in your case it sort of will be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not solve my problem: I would have to edit the settings.py frequently in a running production environment. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not certain that I understand why you think you would need to edit the settings file in production for this to work? Perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: The background process controls the user authentification and registration of new users.An user starting a project there or and so on, does that in the frontend and the frontend gives that information to the backend which controls the user's rights and performs the user actions when the permissions are ok. Still the user will want to see his project status in his frontend, so he needs read access thru the frontend for his tables. In order not to bother the backgound so much especially not with realtime-read, we want all read access directly on the database and all write access thru the backend

Comment: Okay, then my answer above is the easiest way I can think of to achieve that. There would be no reason to edit the settings.py in live (beyond the initial configuration). You can put whatever logic you like in to your router, allowing you to ensure users have the correct permissions, or do whatever else you wish. So if you would like the to be able to create their account/whatever, but not be able to write to the db again, you can do that.